# How do I calculate correct with Modulus %? C# Console App

Tags: c#, math, console, modulo

how do I get the correct output when doing equations with modulus?
This is made in a Console Application.

For example:

**float equation = (35 + 5) % 3;**

output: 1, when the correct answer should be 1.2.

I've tried
float equation = (35 + 5) % 3f;

or

Console.WriteLine((float)equation);

But I dont really know how to make it work. Super grateful for any response.

Comment: 1 is the correct answer, why do you think it should be 1.2? What do you think the modulus operator (%) should do? I would expect the answer 1 because (35 + 5) is 40, and 40 % 3 should return the remainder when dividing 40 by 3. 40/3 = 13 remainder 1 (i.e. 13 x 3 = 39, so the remainder is 40 - 39 = 1). Do you have a different understanding of modulus?

Comment: i would _love_ to hear your reasoning as to why the modulus of two integers should _ever_ result in anything other than an integer.

Comment: Looking at this from another angle, if you know 1.2 is the answer you expect and you guessed that modulus might be the right way to get that answer, please can you explain why 1.2 is the right answer for your situation? It might be that someone can then help you work out how to achieve the result you want.

Comment: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#floating-point-remainder) is the documentation

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 0):

Modulus give you the rest of an integer division:

```
40/3 = 13
13 * 3 = 39
40 - 39 = 1
```

1 is the rest

Comment: Dumb example by me, sorry. What about this: 

(30+9) % 6 = gets the answer 3 in my Console App.

39 / 6 = 6.5

6.5 * 6 = 39

Comment: INTEGER DIVISION !!!!
39 / 6 = 6 !!!

Comment: But what if I dont want it to be integer division, is it not possible?

Comment: Modulus is always integer. If you have a floating point division you never have a rest and you don't need modulus at all.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks alot. So I need to remake the equation to get rid of the modulus. Correct?

Comment: You can change to `(35.0 + 5.0) / 3` then you get 13.33333333 and so on as result (as long as float reaches)
But we have no idea what you want to calculate and if that is correct for you.
If you would use `(35 + 5) / 3` you would have an integer division too and result is 13.